# PHP Group Dates by Year / season

Tags: php, date

I need to group dates by its year and season
the goal is to achieve a drop down menu like this:

- 2001
  -- Summer 
  –- Winter
- 2002 
  -- Summer 
  –- Winter 
  ...
- 2015 
  -- Summer

this is my test code so long,
this code generate a list with every post for one year/period,
how can I modify this to only show if there are posts for this period.
(if so show the year/season in a dropdown)

```
foreach ($event as $post) {
 setup_postdata($post);

 $printdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'datum', 'true'));

  $year =  $printdate->format('Y');
 // I want to use the year to group the posts


 // this is the first period
 $start_date     = $year.'-01-1'; 
 $end_date      = $year.'-06-31';
 $date_from_user = $printdate->format('Y-m-d');

if (( $date_from_user >= $start_date ) && ( $date_from_user <= $end_date  ) )
{ ?>
   <h3><?php echo $year; ?></h3>
   <h4> Summer </h4>
<? }            



 // this is the second period (or i use simply "else" here)
$start_date2     = $year.'-07-1';     
$end_date2      = $year.'-12-31';

if (( $date_from_user >= $start_date2 ) && ( $date_from_user <= $end_date2 ) )                   
{  ?>
   <h3><?php echo $year; ?></h3>
   <h4> Winter </h4>
<? }

}
   ?>
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you pulling these events from a database? You can sort the query by year and month. Then, you can print the year/season every time a row has a year/season that is different from the last one.

Comment: the dates coming from a wordpress query:  
$event = get_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key' => 'date'
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC'
                ));

Comment: If you absolutely cannot sort the events on the query, what I would do is make a new array of event dates. The key is all that matters, not the events. Store YearSeason (e.g. 2012Summer) as the key. The value can be anything (even null). That will give you a unique set of years and seasons. Run ksort - you now have a sorted list of used years and seasons. Run foreach($eventtimes as $yearseason=>$v) .... and you can print what  you need.